# How to perform two-sample t-tests in Excel by inputting sample statistics rather than the raw data?

Tags: t-test, excel

I have large data sets that I can easily summarize in Excel Pivot tables. I would like to be able to use that summary data (Means, St. Dev, n) to write a formula to get the t-value and if possible look up the p-value.I have found StatPlus that works as an add-in, but it requires manually entering each pair of data and them copying the values for t and p into my table.

Comment: Some statistical software will do t tests based on sample sizes, means, and SDs. But risky without the original data, it is not feasible to judge normality (boxplots, normal probability plots, etc.) // If your software insists on data, you can contrive normal data having $n,\bar X, S$ and use that. // Start by simulating a std normal sample of size $n,$ adjust it to get a sample of $Z_i$s with exactly $0$ mean and SD $1,$ Then multiply $Z_i$s by $S$ and add $\bar X.$ If 2-sample test contrive $Y_i$s similarly. Finally, use the $X_i$s (and if relevant $Y_i$s) to do a t test in your software.